# How to check what Angular version was used

Tags: angular, jqwidget

After I've cloned JQWidget Github repository and installed the `angular-fitnesstracker` app with:

```
git clone https://github.com/jqwidgets/jQWidgets.git
cd ./jQWidgets/demos/Showcase/angular-fitnesstracker/
npm install
ng serve
```

I've got an example `angular-fitnesstracker` app up and running. It is accessible in the web browser on http://localhost:4200/

I've noticed that the log in the terminal (after I've executed `npm install`) was a bit different from that what I usually see making me believe that the `angular-fitnesstracker` app was build with the previous version of Angular. I've looked at its `package.json` file and it appears it has a quite different json structure defined there (different from what I've got in the app created with `ng new my-app-name` for example).

How can I check what Angular version was used to build the `angular-fitnesstracker` project?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/jqwidgets/jQWidgets/blob/master/demos/Showcase/angular-fitnesstracker/package.json? The structure is different partly because it's the published version, but you can see all of the versions there still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are using `"@angular/core": "^4.2.6"`

You can see it in this file https://github.com/jqwidgets/jQWidgets/blob/master/demos/Showcase/angular-fitnesstracker/package.json

At the dependencies section